# How to perform prediction with a trained model in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification, prediction

I'm new to Keras. With transfer learning following an online tutorial, I tried to train a model for my custom dataset and below is my code. Now how should I perform classification given an image?

Here is the training code:

```
def build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout, fc_layers, num_classes):
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    for fc in fc_layers:
        # New FC layer, random init
        x = Dense(fc, activation='relu')(x) 
        x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

    # New softmax layer
    predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x) 
    finetune_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
    return finetune_model

train_datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR, 
                                                    target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH), 
                                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
base_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3))

root=TRAIN_DIR
class_list = [ item for item in os.listdir(root) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, item)) ]
print (class_list)

FC_LAYERS = [1024, 1024]
dropout = 0.5

finetune_model = build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout=dropout, fc_layers=FC_LAYERS, num_classes=len(class_list))
adam = Adam(lr=0.00001)
finetune_model.compile(adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
filepath="./checkpoints/" + "MobileNetV2_{epoch:02d}_{acc:.2f}" +"_model_weights.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor=["acc"], verbose=1, mode='max', save_weights_only=True)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

history = finetune_model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, workers=8, 
                                       steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
                                       shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

And here is my classify code, which only returns an array of float numbers!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = load_model('ResNet50_model_weights.h5')

    img_path = 'test.jpg'
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(300, 300))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    print('Input image shape:', x.shape)

    results = model.predict(x)
    print('Predicted:', results)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models' last layer is `softmax`, which means that it outputs probabilities for each class between 0 and 1. In order to tell which class the input image is predicted to be, take the `argmax` of results. `argmax` returns the index of the maximum element in the array.

```
predicted_class_label = np.argmax(results)
print("network predicted input image is class {}".format(predicted_class_label))
```

Comment: Thanks. But can't I get the real name of the class instead of the index?! How to get that? Don't we have `decode_predictions(preds)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what dataset you're working with. Typically, you define the mapping from index to real name. How many classes are you working with and how do you encode the labels?

Comment: I read the names from folders in the current directory (code above!). So the model doesn't remember the real names?!

Comment: Another question: I have a second model with `MobileNetV2`, with only difference that I chose `save_weights_only=True` on the training. But it doesn't work. Any changes required?

Comment: if I want to change my multi-class training to only binary, what should I change? I changed it to `finetune_model.compile(adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`, but I get an error saying `KeyError: 'acc'`.

Comment: You will need to change the last layer of your network to have 1 node, and the activation will need to change from ```softmax``` to ```sigmoid```. I can't debug the ```KeyError``` without knowing more - maybe post a stack trace. Also, to assign names to class labels, you have to define a mapping from the folders in the current directory to an integer.

Comment: can you answer my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919494/my-simple-keras-prediction-shows-wrong-prediction